# WorksheetFunction error sub or function not defined

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, worksheet-function

I was wondering if someone could assist me please. I have created a very simple userform to log information. My issue is however when one of the fields is blank I am receiving an error message :

> Sub or Function not defined.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a Name number
    If Trim(QueryType.Value) = "" Then
        QueryType.SetFocus
            MsgBox "Please complete the form"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'copy the data to the database
    ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Format(Now, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Format(Now, "HH:MM")
    ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Application.UserName
    ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = CType.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = IName.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = QType.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = 1
    ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Format(Date, "MMM-YY")
    'ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(InternalName.Value, Sheet2.Range("C1:D23"), 2, 0)
    'ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(VLookup(InternalName.Value, Sheet2.Range("C1:D23"), 2, 0), "")
   ws.Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(InternalName.Value, Sheet2.Range("C1:E23"), 3, 0)
    ws.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = "IB"

Unload Me

MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"

End Sub
```

The issue is in either one of the commented out lines where I receive the error. I only receive if I leave the dropdown box empty. If populated then no error occurrs. I could easily fit an extra menu option for "Not Applicable" however would rather it was just blank. Does anyone have any suggestions at all please?

Comment: which line is highlighted when you debug?

Comment: @Kelaref whichever iRow, 9 I uncomment. Sorry I should have said. I originally had it as just a vlookup. When I got the error I thought an Iferror function would resolve the issue however it yields the same outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things.

1- `VLookup` is not a VBA function on its own, it's a member method of either the `Application` object or the `WorksheetFunction` object. So you should qualify `VLookup` by either, *even if* you had it inside another method, such as `WorksheetFunction.IfError(...)`.

```
ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = 
WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(InternalName.Value, Sheet2.Range("C1:D23"), 2, 0), "")
'                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

2- The same methods in `WorksheetFunction` and in `Application` objects work differently. In the former, an error is raised in VBA if the result is an error (such as: no match for the searched value). In the latter, no error is raised, but the returned value is an `Error Variant`. This latter form is usually safer for VBA, because you dont need to have some `On Error Resume Next` or so, but you can just check the result with `If(IsError(result))`.

3- When your search criteria is empty or unmatched, you had the error raised due to the use of `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` (According to 2). If your intention is to just set the resulting value and proceed, you can use `Application.VLookup` instead:

```
ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(InternalName.Value, Sheet2.Range("C1:D23"), 2, 0), "")
```

p.s. I personally prefer `Application.` most of the time. Some prefer `WorksheetFunction` mostly because it offers Intellisense, but I find that pretty useless, because the arguments of the methods in Intellisense are unnamed and untyped, i.e. `VLookup(arg1, arg2, arg3, [arg4])`.. (non-sense to me).